# Powershell giving a "Python was not found in the path" error

Tags: python, azure, powershell, deadlines

Forgive me for probably a dumb question.  I'm trying to install an Azure plugin via a script, with very simple instructions [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-deadline/blob/master/README.md)

I've installed Python 2.7, but I'm getting a python not found error, outlined below in the powershell script.  What would be the cause of this?

The error is in the separate block below.  What does that code mean?

Thanks for your help

```
Param(
    [string]$deadlineRepositoryPath = $null,
    [string]$installPath = "$env:ProgramFiles\Microsoft\Azure Deadline",
    [switch]$clientOnlyInstall
)

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = "tls12, tls11, tls"

function Parse-IniFile($file) {
  $ini = @{}

  # Create a default section if none exist in the file. Like a java prop file.
  $section = "NO_SECTION"
  $ini[$section] = @{}

  switch -regex -file $file {
    "^\[(.+)\]$" {
      $section = $matches[1].Trim()
      $ini[$section] = @{}
    }
    "^\s*([^#].+?)\s*=\s*(.*)" {
      $name,$value = $matches[1..2]
      # skip comments that start with semicolon:
      if (!($name.StartsWith(";"))) {
        $ini[$section][$name] = $value.Trim()
      }
    }
  }
  $ini
}


function Create-Directory($dir)
{
    try {
        New-Item $dir -ItemType directory -Force -ea stop | Out-Null
    } catch {
        Write-Error "Could not create install directory $dir, do you have permissions?"
        exit 1
    }
}


function Install-Plugin-Dependencies()
{
    # Install the Azure cloud provider plugin dependencies
    Write-Host "Installing Azure Cloud Plugin dependencies to $installPath..."
    $packagePath = "$installPath\site-packages"
    Create-Directory $packagePath
    & pip.exe install --target="$packagePath" --upgrade -r "$tempPath\azure-deadline-$version\CloudProviderPlugin\requirements.txt" 2>&1 | Out-File "$tempPath\pip.log"
    if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0)
    {
        Write-Error "An error occurred installing one or more packages."
        Get-Content $tempPath\pip.log | foreach {Write-Output $_}
        exit 1
    }

    # Keyring causes issues in Deadline 7.2 and isn't needed any more.
    Remove-Item -Recurse -Force "$packagePath\keyring"

    # Set an environment variable so the plugin knows where to find them
    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_DEADLINE_PLUGIN_PATH", "$installPath", "Machine")
    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_DEADLINE_REPO_PATH", "$deadlineRepositoryPath", "Machine")
}


function Install-CloudProvider-Plugin()
{
    # Install the cloud plugin into the Deadline repository
    $deadlineCloudPluginPath = "$deadlineRepositoryPath\custom\cloud\AzureBatch"
    Create-Directory $deadlineCloudPluginPath
    Write-Host "Installing Azure cloud provider plugin to $deadlineCloudPluginPath..."
    Copy-Item -Path "$tempPath\azure-deadline-$version\CloudProviderPlugin\*" -Destination "$deadlineCloudPluginPath" -Exclude "test_*.py" -Force
}


function Install-DataTransfer-Plugin()
{
    # Install the data transfer plugin into the Deadline repository
    $deadlineDataXferPluginPath = "$deadlineRepositoryPath\custom\events\AzureDataTransfer"
    Create-Directory $deadlineDataXferPluginPath
    Write-Host "Installing Azure data transfer plugin to $deadlineDataXferPluginPath..."
    Copy-Item -Path "$tempPath\azure-deadline-$version\AzureDataTransferEventPlugin\*" -Destination "$deadlineDataXferPluginPath" -Exclude "test_*.py" -Force
}


if ('' -eq $deadlineRepositoryPath)
{
    $deadlineRepositoryPath = Read-Host -Prompt 'Deadline 7.2, 8, 9 or 10 Repository Path'
}

if (!(Test-Path $deadlineRepositoryPath))
{
    Write-Error "The Deadline respository path is invalid or not accessible: $deadlineRepositoryPath"
    exit 1
}

$deadlineRepoConfig = "$deadlineRepositoryPath\settings\repository.ini"
if (!(Test-Path "$deadlineRepoConfig"))
{
    Write-Error "Cannot load the Deadline repository configuration file: $deadlineRepoConfig"
    exit 1
}

$repoConfig = Parse-IniFile -file $deadlineRepoConfig
$deadlineVersion = $repoConfig["DeadlineRepository"]["Version"]
$deadlineMajorVersion = $deadlineVersion.Split(".")[0]

if (!$deadlineVersion.StartsWith("10.") -and !$deadlineVersion.StartsWith("7.2."))
{
    Write-Error "Unsupported Deadline version found: $deadlineVersion"
    exit 1
}

Write-Host "Found Deadline $deadlineVersion in $deadlineRepositoryPath"
```

#

```
try {
    $python = & python.exe -V 2>&1 | %{ "$_" }
} catch {
    Write-Error "Python was not found in the path."
    exit 1
}
```

#

```
if(!$python.StartsWith("Python 2.7"))
{
    Write-Error "Python >= 2.7 was not found in the path."
    exit 1
}

$pythonPath = Get-Command python.exe | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Definition
Write-Host "Found $python at $pythonPath"

$pipPath = "pip.exe"
try {
    $pip = & $pipPath -V 2>&1 | %{ "$_" }
} catch {
    try {
        $pipPath = "${pythonPath}\Scripts\pip.exe"
        $pip = & $pipPath -V 2>&1 | %{ "$_" }
    } catch {
        Write-Error "Pip was not found in the path."
        exit 1
    }
}

$installPath = "$installPath $deadlineMajorVersion"
Create-Directory $installPath

$tempPath = "${env:TEMP}\Microsoft\AzureDeadline$deadlineMajorVersion"
if (Test-Path $tempPath)
{
    Remove-Item $tempPath -Force -Recurse -ea stop
}

Create-Directory $tempPath

$version = "0.7"
$file = "v${version}.zip"
$url = "https://github.com/Azure/azure-deadline/archive/$file"
$localFile = "$tempPath\$file"

# Download the release
Write-Host "Downloading release $url to $localFile"
(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url, "$localFile")

# Extract the release to the temp location
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($localFile, $tempPath)

Install-Plugin-Dependencies

if ($clientOnlyInstall)
{
    exit 0
}

Install-CloudProvider-Plugin
Install-DataTransfer-Plugin
```

Comment: Make sure Python exe is added to your path. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows

Comment: Nailed it. Thanks.  Had to add %PYTHONPATH% in my PATH as well.

Comment: You could add an answer for others to refer.